# GraphQL mutation throwing error

Tags: javascript, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

## Update

I've narrowed down to where the error is being thrown and it seems to be a `Prisma` issue.

The error occurs here within the vote function:

```
const linkExists = await context.db.exists.Vote({
    user: { id: userId },
    link: { id: args.linkId }
})
```

## Original

I'm working my way through [this tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/7-subscriptions/).

I'm trying to "vote" for a post, but it throws the following error:

```
{
  "data": {
    "vote": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable '$_v0_where' cannot be non input type 'VoteWhereInput'. 
                  (line 1, column 20):\nquery ($_v0_where: VoteWhereInput) 
                  {\n                   ^",
      "locations": [],
      "path": [
        "votes"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The mutation I'm sending is:

```
mutation{
  vote(linkId:"cjit726cxfkpj0a21z74nuncu"){
    id
  }
}
```

Not exactly sure what this error means. I've been comparing my code to the [official repo on Github](https://github.com/howtographql/graphql-js), but I can't find the difference.

Here's my vote function:

```
async function vote(parent, args, context, info) {
  const userId = getUserId(context)
  const linkExists = await context.db.exists.Vote({
    user: { id: userId },
    link: { id: args.linkId },
  })
  if (linkExists) {
    throw new Error(`Already voted for link: ${args.linkId}`)
  }

  return context.db.mutation.createVote(
    {
      data: {
        user: { connect: { id: userId } },
        link: { connect: { id: args.linkId } },
      },
    },
    info,
  )
}
```

When I log out `args` it shows:

```
query:
query ($_v0_where: VoteWhereInput) {
  votes(where: $_v0_where) {
    id
  }
}
operationName: null
variables:
{
  "_v0_where": {
    "link": {
      "id": "cjit5v46i2r3y0a21a7ez0t9p"
    },
    "user": {
      "id": "cjis44x27gbn60a219abasvjz"
    }
  }
}
```

I've created a new user, created a post with that user (both work fine), but when I try to vote as that user I get stuck here.

My `datamodel.schema` if you want:

```
type Link {
  id: ID! @unique
  description: String!
  url: String!
  postedBy: User
  votes: [Vote!]!
}

type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  name: String!
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
  links: [Link!]!
  votes: [Vote!]!
}

type Vote {
  id: ID! @unique
  link: Link!  
  user: User!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because the structure of `db.exists`  requires sending arguments wrapped in a `where` field.

[image]
Looks like that docs are outdated, will get [them updated](https://github.com/prismagraphql/prisma/issues/2685) as well.